# Can anyone translate this code into simpler one?

Tags: syntax, code-review

I'm new in Mathematica, so can anyone translate the following code into a simpler form where uses more familiar syntax? my mean is `#`,`&`and `/@` signs. I read about every sign individually in Mathematica documentation but this code has mixed all of them and is not clear to me. Thanks in advance.

```
f[n_] := Orthogonalize[r^# & /@ Range[0, n], Integrate[g*#1*#2, {r, -∞, ∞}] &]
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the author of the code?

Comment: `r^# & /@ Range[0, n]` = `r^Range[0, n]`.  In this case, you can replace `g*#1*#2` by `g * ##`, but my guess is that it is not more familiar (to you).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it might be helpful to evaluate the arguments on their own and see what happens.

The first argument

```
r^# & /@ Range[0, n]
```

outputs (for a specific choice of `n`)

```
With[{n = 3}, r^# & /@ Range[0, n]]
(* {1, r, r^2, r^3} *)
```

which generates a list that you could also get by the following

```
Table[r^i, {i, 0, n}]
```

The `FullForm` of the first argument would be something like

```
Map[Function[{x}, r^x], Range[0, n]]
```

note that `f /@ list` is a shorthand for `Map[f, list]` and, for the sake of a simple unrelated example, `f /@ {1, 2, 3}` gives `{f[1], f[2], f[3]}`.
Now back to the problem at hand: The syntax `r^# &` generates a pure (anonymous) function; you can check that `r^# & [exponent] == r^exponent` where on the left-hand side the function `r^# &` is called with the argument `exponent`.
Note that the ampersand `&` simply tells Mathematica when the pure function definition is complete.

The second argument of `Orthogonalize` is the inner product with respect to which the vectors should be orthogonalized. It is a (pure) function that takes two arguments. When you have more than one argument in a pure function, the slots are numbered and denoted as `#1`, `#2`, etc. A silly example

```
`Sqrt[#1 + #2] &[a, b] == Sqrt[a + b]`
```

Now the second argument is written as

```
`Integrate[g*#1*#2, {r, -∞, ∞}] &`
```

If you like you can define the function explicitly

```
myInnerProd[v1_, v2_] := Integrate[g*v1*v2, {r, -∞, ∞}]
```

and then define

```
f[n_] := Orthogonalize[Table[r^i, {i,0, n}], myInnerProd]
```

If you want to understand better the syntax of pure functions read the documentation entry [`tutorial/FunctionalOperations#17469`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#17469).

Comment: Thanks, and  how `#1*#2` works? what does it mean?

Comment: #1 and #2 are slots - anonymous arguments. When you orthogonalize, the process passes the vectors into #1, #2, just like v1*v2 above. One of the simpler ways to orthogonalize is using [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram–Schmidt_process) and even though it's not used here, it explains it quite well. When you see $\langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{u} \rangle$, you're doing an inner (dot) product. But since our inner product is on functions, not vectors, we do an integral of a product of polynomials over -∞, ∞ weighted by g. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: These are legitimate questions. Why not properly extend the answer to explain every point?

Comment: @flinty Thanks a lot. Now tell me how Mathematica understands where to get `#1` and `#2`? They refer to first and second terms of first argument (`r^# & /@ Range[0, n]`)? and what is the single `&` at the end?

Comment: `&` ends the definition of a pure function. So if I do `f = # + 1 &` that means define a function with an anonymous argument. I can then do `f[4]` and I get result `5`. You should read the tutorial Natas referenced in this answer. On the other point, Mathematica doesn't get #1 and #2 from there exactly. In this case it generates vectors during the orthogonalization process which is kind of complicated to explain here. Read the article about Gram-Schmidt in my earlier comment. It provides #1 and #2 - slots for vectors - for you to use in your own custom inner product, like the Integrate above..

Comment: @flinty good hints,many thanks. Also I should inform you that unfortunately your code (about my previous question that you answered) failed again for another end of spectrum of `a` and `b` where the values change to: `a=0.80847` and `b=4988.41759`. I thought the problem was fixed by normalization factor, but it was not!

Comment: @Natas Thanks a lot for your detailed answer.